# feeds arbitration - suggest algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Many (if not all) major stock exchanges required "feeds arbitration" [described here](http://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/EPICSANDBOX/Market+Data+-+Incremental+Feed+Arbitration)

Many companies implement it in their products - for example [here](http://www.b2bits.com/trading_solutions/market-data-solutions/cme_fast_adaptor.html) (Automatically arbitrates between Feed A and Feed B) or [here](http://www.onixs.biz/cme-fix-fast-market-data-handler.html) (Arbitration between A and B feeds.)

This feature become very common and popular it's mandatory on most stock exchanges and it's implemented probably in every implementations.

However all of these implementations are proprietary I can not find any open source implementations.

(Also I think this task is very interesting by itself. We can apply it anywhere where we want "low latency and at the same time high reliable" delivery, probably in live video processing or something.)

So the question is - if there are any good open source feed a/b arbitration implementation? Or how should I implement it - how many threads do I need to arbitrate, how to do it. (I'm almost obviosly need at least two threads - one to receive packets from FeedA and one to receive packets from FeedB)